# How to declare a Kotlin type of a fixed set of strings?

Tags: kotlin

In Typescript I can declare a limited set of strings as a type:

```
declare type Status = 'GOOD' | 'MEDIUM' | 'POOR';
```

and I can then use this type to restrict the strings assigned to the `status` property:

```
interface Foo {
  status: Status;
}
```

How do I do that in Kotlin?

Comment: You can't do that directly. You can declare an enum and convert each enum entry from/to a string if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin, you would create an `enum` for this

```
enum class Status {
    GOOD, MEDIUM, POOR
}
```

In this basic case, you can then use the `enum` constant's `name` as follows:

```
val state: Status = Status.MEDIUM
val stateString: String = state.name
```

If you want to have more sophisticated enums, you can give them custom properties:

```
enum class Status(val description: String) {
    GOOD("Good State"), MEDIUM("Medium State"), POOR("Poor State")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @s1m0nw1 - if the strings had spaces or other wacky characters how would you change the solution?

Comment: You can add properties to enums like with normal classes. I will adjust the answer